# Transpose notation question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

In a course I am undertaking, I was exposed to the following notation for **Taylor's theorem**:

Fix $x^∗ , x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ and assume that $f : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}$ has continuous first and second partial derivatives on some open set containing the line segment $[x, x^∗ ]$. Then there exists $z ∈ [x, x^∗ ]$ such that

$f (x) = f (x^∗ ) + ∇f (x^∗ )^T (x − x^∗ ) + \frac{1}{2} (x − x^∗ )^T ∇^2 f (x^∗ )(x − x^∗ ) + o(\|x − x^∗\|^2 )$

My main concern is in understanding the meaning and use of the added "$^T$" in this theorem, but also the small $o$.  I know there have been previous threads in regards to the small $o$ notation, but was still undecidedly sure in this context?

Is the "$^T$" used to extend taylor's theorem in n-dimensions for our example? Why is there a transpose in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, what you want to do where you see the transpose notation is take a dot product, which you are possibly used to seeing as $a\cdot b$. However, you may also think of a dot product as a matrix multiplication, as a vector is a matrix with only one column or row.

Recall the rule for when matrices can be multiplied. If we define a matrix as being of dimensions $(a \times b)$, with $a$ being the number of rows and $b$ being the number of columns, we can say that:

$$(a_{1} \times b_{1})(a_{2} \times b_{2}) \text{ has dimensions } (a_{1} \times b_{2})$$

iff $b_{1} = a_{2}$, otherwise, those matrices cannot be multiplied together. So, if your vectors are of size $(n,1)$ (i.e. column vectors), you cannot directly multiply them together. Taking the tranpose of the first one allows you to multiply matrices of size:

$$(1 \times n)(n \times 1) = (1 \times 1) = \text{scalar}$$

As for the little-o notation, this is used to quantify the way one number relates to another number $\textit{in the limit}$ as $x \to x^{*}$. This doesn't tell us anything about the exact value the error takes, but simply that is is $\textit{much smaller}$ than $||x - x^{2}||^{2} \text{ as } x \to x^{*}$.

EDIT: Just re-reading the question and realised I forgot to mention something. You are correct about the intention being to extend Taylor's theorem in $n$ dimensions. It is not the transpose which does this, per se, rather, the transpose becomes necessary when you make $x$ a vector instead of a scalar.

Comment: @yaweh: NB my edit to include the other part of the question I forgot. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

We view $x, x^*$ and hence also $x-x^*$ as column vectors, likewise $\nabla f(x^*)$. Hence $\nabla f(x^*)^T$ is a row vector and the product of row times column vector is just a scalar (just as we need). Morevover, $\nabla^2 f(x^*)$ is a matrix and row times matrix times column is also a scalar.

The little $o$ expresses that the differene between $f(x)$ and the right hand side (without the $o$ expression) is significantly samller than $\|x-x^*\|^2$, i.e., that the error divided by $\|x-x^*\|^2$ tends to $0$ as $x\to x^*$.

Comment: So essentially "the error" is also denoted as $o(\|x-x^*\|)^2$ and this is the difference between $f(x)$ and RHS?

Comment: also thank you a lot for your response, I really appreciate it.